# Debug a simple C program

Tags: c

I'm new to C. For the following program, the problem is: whatever integer I input, the output is 1. Can you tell me where the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    n = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `scanf()`? It doesn't seem to me you did.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are printing the return value of `scanf()`. scanf() returns the number of values successfully scanned.

Change the line:

```
n = scanf("%d", &n);
```

to:

```
 scanf("%d", &n);
```

Or if you want to verify whether the input was sucessful, use a different variable:

```
if (scanf("%d", &n)! = 1 ) {
   /* Input failure */
}
```

Comment: If scanf returns the number of values successfully scanned, then what does a return value of `EOF` indicate? That a negative number of values were scanned? Heh...

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` return the number of valid values read. In your example, first the value is read into `n` which is further replaced by the return value of `scanf` which is always `1` in your current implementation, as long you enter a valid integer as the input.

Comment: It's *always 1?!* It's over nine thousand!

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I have updated my comment. I didn't get your comment on over nine thousane part

Comment: http://ideone.com/EHx88r

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thanks.. When I referred to the C11 standard draft, I find the return value of scanf to be number of items read. Reference: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf Page no. 343, Section no.7.21.6.4, point 3. I tried your example on VS2010 and I don't get an assert. I am aware that VS2010 doesn't support C99/C11 standard, but I am not sure why it would return anything else, unless you don't input data.

Comment: 7.21.6.4p3 (the section you're quoting) begins with "The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed." Does this mean "the return value of scanf is always 1", or "the return value of scanf is the number of items read"? No. Did you try my example, with "invalid input" as input, or CTRL+Z? No; You would have gotten an assertion.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue If your point is about EOF, then you are right. However this question is very simple about a programming error if I may term so. It wasn't about exploring all the possibilities of `scanf`. In any case, I have updated my comment.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` returns the number of items sucessfully read. So if you assign it to `n`, then `n` will contain 1 (in case the integer is read without error).

All in all: change your code to

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

and read a good book on C.

Comment: Section 7.1.4p3: "There is a sequence point immediately before a library function returns."

Comment: Aside from that discrepancy, this is actually my favorite answer.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thank you for the correction, accepted your edit.

Answer (score 0):

your error is in the

> n = scanf("%d", &n);

Change it into

> `scanf("%d", &n);`

it should be fine then

Comment: This seems to be a copy of kingsindian's answer.

Comment: sorry i did not see his answer when i was posting mine. it's a pretty standard mistake